# Retorno do valor Maximo

Tags: sql, sqlite

Bom dia, estou realizando um curso e estou travado em um exercício.

No exercício eu tenho que retornar o valor máximo de popularidade de cada genero musical por país, até ai tudo bem, consegui realizar o procedimento, o problema é que no exercício tem país que o valor maximo de popularidade repete, ou seja, tem país que pode ter dois generos musicais de igual popularidade.

Gostaria de saber como faço para exibir os dois generos, tendo em vista que quando coloco GROUP BY ele agrupa tudo e exibe apenas um país, e se tem outro forma de fazer isso sem sub-consulta

```
SELECT MAX(total) total, pais, genero, id_genero
FROM(SELECT Count(*) total, BillingCountry pais, g.Name genero, g.GenreId id_genero
        FROM Genre g
        JOIN Track t
        ON g.GenreId = t.GenreId
        JOIN InvoiceLine il
        ON t.TrackId = il.TrackId
        JOIN Invoice i
        ON il.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
        GROUP BY 2, 3
        ORDER BY 2, 1 DESC)t1
GROUP BY 2
```

[image: Modelo de Dados]

[image: Resultado a ser obtido]

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta o seu modelo de dados e se possível umas 2 linhas com dados para entendermos melhor?

Comment: No fina, cê está setando um group by 2, tecnicamente, dependendo do caso, tu sempre vai ter o retorno de uma coluna mesmo, deu uma observada nisso? se for algo da sintaxe no sgbd que tu tá usando, ignora o comentário então ...

Comment: Ricardo, coloquei o modelo de dados e o resultado que eu tenho que chegar

Comment: Dica , use um subselect com MAX ( https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/512214-selecionando-item-max/?do=findComment&comment=2030107 )

Comment: Motta, voce diz para eu fazer uma outra consulta no select que ja tem o MAX?

Comment: Motta, consegui, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Com este codigo abaixo, caso haja generos com valores iguais ele vai trazer os dois.

OBS:Deixei o codigo o mais espaço possivel para melhor entendimento.

SELECT T1.*
FROM 
(SELECT 
C.Country,
G.name,
COUNT(*) QTD
FROM Genre G
JOIN Track T
ON G.Genreid = T.Genreid
JOIN InvoiceLine IL
ON T.Trackid = IL.Trackid
JOIN Invoice I
ON IL.Invoiceid = i.Invoiceid
JOIN Customer C
ON I.Customerid = C.Customerid
GROUP BY 1,2) T1

JOIN

(SELECT Country,Max(QTD) QTD
FROM 
(SELECT 
C.Country,
G.name,
COUNT(*) QTD
FROM Genre G
JOIN Track T
ON G.Genreid = T.Genreid
JOIN InvoiceLine IL
ON T.Trackid = IL.Trackid
JOIN Invoice I
ON IL.Invoiceid = i.Invoiceid
JOIN Customer C
ON I.Customerid = C.Customerid
GROUP BY 1,2)
GROUP BY 1) T2
ON 
T1.Country = T2.Country
AND 
T1.QTD = T2.QTD